# Find P(T$\geq$ 3) for Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Given the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ with state space $\mathcal{S}=\lbrace 0, 1,2 \rbrace$ and transition probability matrix $\mathbf{P} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
{\textstyle\frac{5}{17}} &{\textstyle\frac{5}{17}} &{\textstyle\frac{7}{17}}\cr
{\textstyle\frac{5}{23}} &{\textstyle\frac{12}{23}} &{\textstyle\frac{6}{23}}\cr
0 &0 &1
\end{array}\right]$

Define by T the time the process first reaches the absorbing state 2

Find P(T $\geq$ 3) given that P($X_0$ = $0$) = $0.3$

So far I have attempted

$P(T \geq 3) = P(X_0 = 0)*P(T \geq 3|X_0 = 0)\\= 0.3 * (1- P(T \leq 2|X_0 = 0))\\ = 0.3 (1- \frac{4375}{6647}) $

to no avail using the fact that normally in probability that $P(X \geq n) = 1- P(X \leq n-1)$

Please help me solve this question and guide me in the right direction

Edit: The question was updated to include the fact that $P(X_0 = 1) = 0.7$

Comment: Hint: Try computing $\Pr(T = 1)$ and $\Pr(T = 2)$ and then use them to compute $\Pr(T \geq 3)$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Would $Pr(T = 1)$ be something like $P(T = 1 | X_0 = 0) = P(T \leq 1 | X_0 = 0) - P(T \leq 0 | X_0 = 0) \\ = P_{02} - 0.3\\= \frac{7}{17} - 0.3$

and

$P(T = 2 | X_0 = 0) = P(T \leq 2 | X_0 = 0) - P(T \leq 1 | X_0 = 0)\\
= P_{02}^2 - P_{02}
\\= \frac{4052}{6647} - \frac{7}{17}$

Comment: And $P(T \geq 3) = 1 - (P(T=1) + P(T=2))$?

Comment: Do you already know that $P(X_0=2)=0$? Otherwise there seems to be insufficient info.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Like the chance that the initial state being state 2 having chance 0? I think the question is asking the probability of reaching state 2 in 3 or more steps by the $P(X_0 = 0) = 0.3$

Comment: Yes but $T$ depends on the initial distribution $v$ where $v_i=P(X_0=i)$. The question has only specified one element of the initial distribution $v_0=0.3$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang If it helps, here are the other parts of the question that I identified
$E[T|X_0 = 0] = \frac{302}{107}\\E[T|X_0=1] = \frac{361}{107}\\P(T>2|X_0=0) = \frac{2595}{6647}\\P(T>2|X_0=1 = \frac{4618}{8993}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that the event $T = n$ implies that $X_n = 2$ and $X_i \neq 2$ for all $i = 0,1,2,\dots,n-1$.

Let us begin with evaluating $\Pr(T = 0)$, $\Pr(T = 1)$ and $\Pr(T = 2)$. Clearly, $\Pr(T = 0) = \Pr(X_0 = 2)$. For $n \geq 1$, $\Pr(T = n|X_0 =2) = 0$ by definition. For $\Pr(T = 1)$, using law of total probability, we have,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(T = 1) & = \sum_{i = 0}^{2} \Pr(T = 1|X_0 = i) \Pr(X_0 = i) \\
& = \Pr(X_1 = 2|X_0 = 0) \Pr(X_0 = 0) + \Pr(X_1 = 2|X_0 = 1) \Pr(X_0 = 1) + 0 \\
& = \frac{7}{17} \cdot \Pr(X_0 = 0) + \frac{6}{23} \cdot \Pr(X_0 = 1).
\end{align*}

For $T = 2$, we first evaluate $\Pr(T = 2|X_0 = 0)$. We have,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(T = 2|X_0 = 0) & = \Pr(X_2 = 2, X_1 \neq 2|X_0 = 0) \\
& =  \Pr(X_2 = 2, X_1 = 0|X_0 = 0) + \Pr(X_2 = 2, X_1 = 1|X_0 = 0)\\
& =  \Pr(X_2 = 2|X_1 = 0) \Pr(X_1 = 0|X_0 = 0) + \Pr(X_2 = 2|X_1 = 1) \Pr(X_1 = 1|X_0 = 0)\\
& = \frac{7}{17} \cdot \frac{5}{17} + \frac{6}{23} \cdot \frac{5}{17}.
\end{align*}
Using a similar approach, we can conclude,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(T = 2|X_0 = 1) = \frac{7}{17} \cdot \frac{5}{23} + \frac{6}{23} \cdot \frac{12}{23}
\end{align*}
Consequently, $\Pr(T = 2) = \Pr(T=2|X_0 = 0) \Pr(X_0 = 0) + \Pr(T=2|X_0 = 1) \Pr(X_0 = 1)$. You can plug in the values and compute that.

Finally, $\Pr(T \geq 3) = 1 - (\Pr(T = 0) + \Pr(T = 1) + \Pr(T = 2))$.

Comment: Would $P(X_0 = 1) = 0$? Since we are only given the probability of starting in state 0 so the initial probability vector would be $[0.3, 0, 0]$ where $P(X_0 = 0) = 0.3$ and $P(X_0 = 1) = 0$?

Comment: $[0.3, 0,0]$ is not a probability vector because the entries don't sum up to $1$. This is exactly what Benjamin was asking in the discussion above that if you have any additional information about this probability vector. If not, there is no way to solve this as there is insufficient information. Once you have that information, you can plug in the values in the method above and get your result.

Comment: The question was updated to include that $P(X_0 = 0) = 0.3, P(X_0 = 1) = 0.7$ which makes $P(X_0 = 2) = 0$. I was able to come up with the values after plugging in the numbers $P(T=0) = 0, P(T = 1) = \frac{1197}{3910},P(T = 2) = \frac{166093}{764405}$, and $P(T \geq 3) = \frac{728597}{1528810}$. Can you verify that these are correct?

Comment: As long as you obtained the values using the relations above, they should be correct. You can double check the arithmetic using a calculator.